# Openwrt linux devices list

Tags: linux, serial-port, openwrt

I want to transfer some serial data as explained here:http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~sexton/ENGD2003/openwrt/arduino%20teensy%20openwrt.html on an openwrt router. However, I directly connected to the serial port of the router as opposed to usb(in the guide) so now I don't know which of the following is the device:

Which one of the following is the serial port of the router?

```
bus        mtd1       mtd5       null       ttyATH0    ttyS15     ttyS9
console    mtd1ro     mtd5ro     port       ttyS0      ttyS2      urandom
full       mtd2       mtdblock0  ppp        ttyS1      ttyS3      watchdog
kmsg       mtd2ro     mtdblock1  ptmx       ttyS10     ttyS4      zero
log        mtd3       mtdblock2  pts        ttyS11     ttyS5
mem        mtd3ro     mtdblock3  random     ttyS12     ttyS6
mtd0       mtd4       mtdblock4  shm        ttyS13     ttyS7
mtd0r
o     mtd4ro     mtdblock5  tty        ttyS14     ttyS8
```

When I connect the device using serial, nothing new shows up so it must be one of those. Any ideas?

Edit:
The results of cat /proc/cmdline
board=TL-WR703N console=ttyATH0,115200 rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2 noinitrd

Comment: How many serial ports does your router provide? Is it your console port where you've attached the other device? Please provide: `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: I updated the question with the results. Sorry, I cant tell how many it provides since I had to solder it. This is what I did: http://www.instructables.com/id/TL-WR703N-serial-port/step4/null/

Comment: How do you connect to the router via SSH? Your port seems to be your console port i.e. `/dev/ttyATH0`, because you have an Atheros SoC.

Comment: I connect to it via the ethernet port.

Comment: Configure `/dev/ttyATH0` in `ser2net` and see, if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are trying to connect Arduino board to your router's console port, that you've soldered. The device name is `/dev/ttyATH0`.

I would make following test. If Arduino sends something on start, you can set the desired baudrate via `stty` and then execute `cat /dev/ttyATH0` and see, if startup message appears.

If Arduino awaits commands, before it sends data, you will need `minicom` or `screen`, so that you can send/receive data over serial link.

**Possible issues**: this port is owned by both kernel (`console=ttyATH0,115200`) and init processes (see `/etc/inittab`), that means, that even if can use the port, kernel messages can interfere with your data.

Comment: Yep thats right. I do have a issue right now and its sending from the arduino seems to close the connection but its probably because I send data before the router has loaded. I only need it one way for now anyway(it works from computer to arduino). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually `/dev/ttyS0` is the first built-in serial port.

Comment: That's true for x86 and 8250 based UARTs, but ARM based systems name their internal UARTs different: TI's OMAPs first serial port is `/dev/ttyO0`, KS8695 - `/dev/ttyAM0` etc.

Comment: @yegorich many OpenWRT devices are MIPS not ARM, and no small number have 8250-style UARTs in the SoC but anyway it ultimately depends on the driver.  /dev/ttyS0 is *extremely common* on OpenWRT.